# Obtain Java 11 for macOS?

Tags: macos, java

I know in recent years the Java development cadence has changed, becoming much more rapid and more predictably scheduled. New plans were announced for regular Long-Term Support (LTS) releases. And I have heard Oracle changed their licensing terms for their Oracle-branded releases.

All of this has left me confused as to how and where I can obtain Java 11 or later for my Mac. Can someone give some general overview of my options?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## tl;dr

If you are an end-user needing a free-of-cost [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) to run a [Java app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)) on your Mac (rather than a [developer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_developer)), my personal recommendation is to download an `.pkg` file from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net).

[image: screenshot of AdoptOpenJDK.net web site page]

Open that file to run a macOS installer.

[image: screenshot of "Install AdoptOpenJDK" installer app running]

You will then find a JVM installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. Later, you can upgrade in the same manner, deleting the old JVM from that folder.

[image: screenshot of Finder showing JavaVirtualMachines folder]

## Details

Yes, there have been several major changes to the evolution of Java in recent years, and they can be a bit confusing.

## Multiple vendors, both free and paid

First, know that there are new options available for those wishing to pay for commercially supported implementations of Java. And know that Java is still available freely without cost. For both a summary as well as the gory details, read this white paper published by major figures in the Java community: [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04)

## OpenJDK

Secondly, know that all releases for Java 11 and later for macOS are based on the same codebase, the open-source project known as [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK).

Apple contributes Mac-specific code to this project, and has staff working on this to make sure that Java continues to work well on macOS.

IBM, Oracle, and many other companies have contributed code and testing as well. Oracle has recently announced their intention to reach feature-parity between their own Oracle-branded Java releases and the OpenJDK product; this even included the donation of some of their previously-commercial tools such as [*Flight Recorder*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328) to OpenJDK.

The upshot is that you should see very similar behavior and features across the various sources of Java for macOS.

## JVM bundled within desktop apps

If you make desktop apps to run locally on a Mac or other computer, you may continue to do so, and keep on using Swing and/or JavaFX as always. But the delivery of your app will change.

[*Java Applet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) and [*Java Web Start*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) technologies are being phased out. Oracle will no longer encourage end-users to have a JVM by itself installed. Instead, Oracle advises building your app as a standalone executable with a JVM bundled inside. This has already been commonly done on Macs, especially so if [delivering an app through the Apple App Store](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20%2Bjava%20apple%20app%20store&t=osx&ia=web). That approach is the new normal, to be done across all platforms including macOS, Windows, Linux, etc.  The new [Java Modularization](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) technology that began with Java 9, including the [*jlink*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282) and [*jpackage*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343) tools, make it easier than ever to [bundle a down-sized JVM](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/275) with your app.

For more info, see the white paper [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf) of 2018-03.

So, for the purpose of bundling with your app, you will need to consider redistribution/deployment rights when choosing a JVM vendor and product.

## Choosing a vendor

Some major vendors of Java to consider for Java 11 and later:

- [**Azul Systems**](https://www.azul.com)
  Offering two product lines, *Zulu* based directly on OpenJDK with possibly a few tweaks, and *Zing* a specially-enhanced version of the Java platform.
- **Oracle**
  Offering their own commercial product [*Oracle JDK*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and the quite-similar free-of-cost and GPL-licensed [*jdk.java.net*](https://jdk.java.net).
- **AdoptOpenJDK.net**
  Offering free-of-cost builds of Java based on OpenJDK. Choose between with the usual [*HotSpot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) engine (just-in-time compiler & optimizer) or the [*OpenJ9*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9) engine from Eclipse (previously from IBM).

Here is a diagram chart that may help guide your decision-making. This chart is not necessarily complete or accurate. It is simply meant to help get you oriented. You should research further your options.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

---

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]

Comment: Say I'm a layperson who just wants to run a random .jar file he found on the internet. In the interest of security, I'd like to run the latest version of java. Following your flowchart, it looks like I need to learn about "Java modularization, jlink, and jpackage", which is already way out of my league. What do I need to download?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I do mention that Oracle no longer encourages end-users directly installing Java on their machine. But you *can* download a JDK which is a JRE plus some developer tools. Long story short: I recommend you [download Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/), specifically the `.DMG` ([Apple disk image file]) to mount on your Mac, inside of which you will find an installer to run. You will then have a JVM installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. Later, you can upgrade in the same manner, deleting the old JVM from that folder. I do this myself.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I added a `tl;dr` section up top with this same personal recommendation.

Comment: @BasilBourque Why don't you recommend the official Java from Oracle for end-users?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Oracle changed the terms of their licensing for *Oracle JDK*. They now require a fee when used in production, while still free-of-cost for development and testing. If you are already a paying Oracle customer, then I certainly do recommend considering *Oracle JDK* as you may already be paying for it (check the terms of your contract). If you want paid support services, then I do indeed recommend considering Oracle as a possible vendor, along with the other JDK vendors listed on the left side of the blue barrel in my diagram, and other service vendors such as New Relic.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen There is nothing “official” about *Oracle JDK* from Oracle. Any implementation from any vendor that meets the requirements of the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) is Java, and will execute any Java program. The only thing “official” is that if a vendor wants to use the *Java* trademark, their implementation must pass a test suite provided by Oracle, and must meet contractual terms presumably including a fee payment. Furthermore, Oracle has announced their intention to keep their commercial product *Oracle JDK* at feature-parity with OpenJDK.

Comment: @BasilBourque Private use is not production so the argument does not apply.  Professional use is another matter - developers machines are not production so the argument does not apply.  I do not know how many people run Java in production on Macs, but they are probably relatively few in this context.  I am very well aware of the relation between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK and the latter has features the former doesn't (hence the reason for the Zulu Commercial Compatibility Kit) and those features may be relevant for those who need full backward compatibility for legacy programs.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen *“There will be zero differences between the OpenJDK and the Oracle JDK”*, [said Mark Cavage](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/10/javaone-opening/), VP of Product Development, Java and Container Native Platform, Oracle.

Comment: WOW. This is an amazing answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have the simplest life possible, install [homebrew](https://brew.sh) and then install java with `brew cask install java`.